# My SQL Server Upgrade from 5.6.12 to 5.6.22

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL Server 5.6.12. I have this server as a windows service.

When i upgraded this, i did the following.

I stopped the service
I copied 5.6.22 server folder, removed the data folder. 
From this folder(without Data Folder), I pasted into 
existing 5.6.12 Server Folder.

I can see the server upgraded to 5.6.22.

But when i query the data, it shows only few rows. My Front End(web URL) shows.
500 rows. So I am not pointing to the correct place? Please advise.

What I am missing? The Disk Space in Data Dir says: unable to retrieve.

Thanks
kp

Comment: Have you backed up the folder's previous contents, and if so, have you tried restoring them (thus downgrading the server version) and running the server afterwards?

Comment: I can try downgrading and see. But if it works when i downgrade then how can i resolve it (when upgrading this comes up). I also read that this may be due to partitioning of DB. I am not a DBA. Need some help

Answer (score 0):

That's a very uncommon way to upgrade.  Instead, leave the data folder in place.

1. backup the data folder.
2. install the new version
3. run `mysql_upgrade`

(No, I can't explain what went wrong with what you did.)